# how to use systrace tool for Jelly Bean Device

Tags: android, debugging

I have some devices which were become slugginese. I would like to debug this device using new Android Jelly Bean systrace. Could any of you please point me to the right tool and how to use it.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Please read http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html page.

And you should have attention that some devices don't have systrace feature.

You must check /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on file on your device.